# ffmpeg PNG to mp4 - Black screen

Tags: ffmpeg, png, mp4, mpeg

I can create a mpg video using this line

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i 100%03d0.png movie.mpg
```

But If I try creating an mp4 video I get a video with a black screen.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i 100%03d0.png movie.mp4
```

My directory with figures looks like:
1000010.png,1000020.png,...1001260.png

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` should solve the problem:

```
ffmpeg -i input_%03d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mp4
```

From [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images):

> "By default when using libx264, and depending on your input, ffmpeg
>   will attempt to avoid color subsampling. Technically this is
>   preferred, but unfortunately almost all video players, excluding
>   FFmpeg based players, and many online video services only support the
>   YUV color space with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.
>
> Using the options `-pix_fmt yuv420p` or `-vf format=yuv420p` will
>   maximize compatibility."

Comment: you were right I can play the video on VLC but not on Quicktime. Adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` solved the problem Thanks